# What is the fastest way copy 800Gb data from Greenplum to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, greenplum

Our company has a base on Greenplum with a total volume of almost 800 GB. What is the fastest way to transfer all data from Greenplum to a clean database on the SQL Server?

Comment: How many tables / rows per table need to be migrated? How fast does it need to be? Is this a one time migration or you'll need to be able to repeat it in the future? There's a multitude of ways to migrate data into SQL Server efficiently, such as BCP, but this will depend on some of the answers to the aforementioned questions.

Comment: Also: are the bigger tables partitioned? Can it be done without the indexes being pre created? What network capacity is available? It will be hard to go faster than that ….

Answer (score 0):

Well, faster in terms of data transfer would be trying to avoid ODBC / JDBC connections, if possible. If not possible, prefer JDBC (type 4) over ODBC.

It also depends on the overall scenario of your architecture, and about that, you did not provide any details by the way.

In general terms, I would try:

1. Unloading tables using writable external tables (https://docs.greenplum.org/6-6/admin_guide/load/topics/g-unloading-data-using-a-writable-external-table.html)
2. Moving files to SQL Server host, and Bulk Loading the data to target tables.

This would be my opinion of a faster way.

**Considerations**

Migrating data from one database to another have a lot of additional considerations, about how are the source tables designed, distributed, partitioned, do you have functions/procedures, etc.